# Android DownloadManager "Unable to create directory: /storage/sdcard/Download"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-download-manager, android-external-storage

When trying to download a file with **DownloadManager** in Android sdk 22 I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /storage/sdcard/Download
        at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:538)
```

The app already has the permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and when checking for it it returns **true**

It also works when using an emulator with sdk version 25

```
val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("https://xxxxxx.xx/public/App/xxx.apk"))
request.setDescription(context.getString(R.string.downloading_description)).setTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "update.apk")
downloadManager.enqueue(request)
context.registerReceiver(onComplete, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
```

This code works on sdk 25

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory in Android 6.0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767923/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-create-directory-in-androi)

Comment: @Arpanßløødyßadßøy But I have both read and write permissions for the external storage (with permission a permission test that returns true)

Comment: @Konrad You've requested the permissions at runtime?

Comment: @earthw0rmjim Exactly: When checking it returns true (WRITE & READ)