# Previous activity visible under the new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I call fragment from activity then fragment calling successfully  but some part of previous activity is on the top of in fragment, anyone help to correct the code

package com.example.newproject;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import static android.view.View.GONE;

public class ThankYouPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button thank_continue_btn,thank_track_btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thank_you_page);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Confirmation");


        thank_continue_btn = findViewById(R.id.thank_continue_btn);
        thank_track_btn = findViewById(R.id.thank_track_btn);




        findViewById(R.id.thank_continue_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {

               FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
               HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
               fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.thanku_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Can you share xml of activity and fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory in Android 6.0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767923/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-create-directory-in-androi)

Comment: The fragment layout has a transparent background. You should add a suitable background color for the fragment layout.

Answer (score 0):

set background to white in the root tag of your fragment's xml

```
background = "#FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score 0):

The container of your Fragment must be overlapped by your Activity layouts. Please attach the layouts of your Activity and Fragment so that I can help you find your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues , i fixed it by removing previous fragment  while setting new fragment in oncreateview

container.removeAllViews(); before replacing the fragment

Comment: container.removeAllViews(); is give error in my activity

Comment: can u post a picture and what is it showing ,  previous fragment content or activity content where you have framelayout ?
Also u dont use this code in activity you use this in your fragment class in oncreateview

Answer (score -1):

`R.id.thanku_container` - I think it is `FrameLayout`?

Make it full match_parent. Or set background color like activity.